# Console.log affect performance ipad webapp?

Tags: javascript, ios, ipad, web-applications, webkit

Will it affect ipad webapp performance when I use console.log to log huge object?

I mean in production, when I use console.log under the background, will it affect performance?

Comment: well you use colsole.log for debugging , its not something user wants to see , and so that no body cares because we remove it in live application

Comment: though _The effects of console logging on the overall memory profile could potentially be a very significant issue that many developers don't even consider. Logging the wrong object can keep large chunks of data in memory_ IBM

Comment: good read https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-memory-profiling

Comment: Nice! Then I need to clear all these object from my console.

Comment: exactly , there is no need to show anything in console to live application